# How to INSERT to two tables from the same SELECT query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this code in `PostgreSQL`:

```
    for row in select .... from .... where ....
    loop
        insert into A(id1,id2,id3,quantity)
               select aa,bb,1,quantity
               from func1(row.idfirst);
   end loop;
```

I want to do another `INSERT` with the same query so I can do this:

```
    for row in select .... from .... where ....
    loop
        insert into A(id1,id2,id3,quantity)
               select aa,bb,1,quantity
               from func1(row.idfirst);

        insert into B(first,second,third,forth)
               select aa,bb,1,quantity
               from func1(row.idfirst);
   end loop;
```

the thing is that it's redundant of the same code... and also `func1` is a huge function. it takes long time for it to work and i'm not crazy to run it twice.

Is there any solution to do two inserts with the same `select` query?

Comment: I don't think so that we can do inserts to multiple tables at once. Inserting multiple values to same table is possible though.

Comment: I think it's possible with `CTE` (`WITH`) I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: Another possible solution is a trigger on insert into A. Whether it's suitable for you depends on semantics of the tables, which we don't know.

Answer (score 2):

You can use CTE in PostgreSQL 9.1+, like this:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    INSERT INTO A(id1,id2,id3,quantity)
               SELECT aa,bb,1,quantity
               FROM func1(row.idfirst);
    RETURNING id1,id2,id3,quantity
    )
INSERT INTO B(first,second,third,forth)
SELECT id1,id2,id3,quantity
FROM CTE;
```